# Add oauth2 provider to existing user system

Tags: authentication, go, oauth-2.0, authorization

Searching for oauth2 stuff seems to bring up dozens of `Q&A`'s on `client-side` integration (like how to authorize with `google/facebook apis`) or using existing providers (like solutions for popular frameworks), but I am having a hard time finding info on building a solution on top of a `pre-existing user/pw db`.

Can someone please outline the bullet points of exactly what it needs to do in order to extend the existing system to provide `oauth2 authorization?` i.e. the existing system already provides registration, password recovery, `login`, `forgot email` - all that stuff without a framework (`golang` and password is hashed with `first x bytes` as `salt`, in case it matters). I don't want to toss it all out in place of an out-of-the-box solution which covers all that + oauth2. I want to add oauth2 by hand (or using *minimal* `golang libraries`) on top of the existing system.

I'm currently trying to reverse engineer and look at existing code, but it's a bit confusing and when it comes to authorization/security stuff I don't want to be making guesses, even educated ones. Could look at the spec too but I don't really need cover everything in there, just the bare minimum to let another site authenticate (by calling a "getprofile" API after authorized, maybe I'll make that compliant with `openid` connect but never mind that for now unless there's no increase in steps).

Sample code or libraries if any are preferred in go-lang since that's what I'm building in, but pseudo-code or vanilla code in other languages is fine too

Comment: https://github.com/RangelReale/osin

Comment: works on top of existing system (i.e. doesn't take over how passwords are stored etc.)?

Comment: Check out the examples on how to integrate.

Comment: Yeah - seems like it might be a good solution, thanks. Still looking for answers to the question though just in case I need to roll my own ;)

Comment: I could answer that as well, as i did exactly that. However it would be way to long as an answer here. So if you have specific questions regarding oauth2  in go, just ask per question. I can tell you though, you will not get around reading the spec if you intend to implement it.